# Can't center an image on a page with links. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to develop a single page like the design in the image below however I can't seem to make it work. The image (smiley face logo) isn't responsive as it doesn't scale down properly to mobile devices. The 'About' and 'Contact' links also does not appear directly under the image either. Any suggestions?

Concept image:
[image: responsive website design concept]

My CSS:

```css
/* Global Styles */

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.CenterScreen{
   position:absolute;
   /*element can move on the screen (only screen, not page)*/

   left:50%;top:50%;
   /*set the top left corner of the element on the center of the screen*/

   transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*reposition element center with screen center*/

}


.text-vertical-center {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;  */
    vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-vertical-center h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.text-vertical-center h3 {
    text-align: left;
}



/* Header */

.header {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
```

My HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Smile test</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/ACo.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="top" class="header">
        <div class="text-vertical-center">

                <img src="img/smile.svg" class="CenterScreen" style="display:inline" alt="Smilelogo" width="800" height="800">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-5">
                    <h3><a href="#">About</a></h3>
                    <h3><a href="#">Contact Us</a></h3>
                </div>                    
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
```

**Complete Code**

```css
html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }

    .CenterScreen{
       position:absolute;
       /*element can move on the screen (only screen, not page)*/

       left:50%;top:50%;
       /*set the top left corner of the element on the center of the screen*/

       transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        /*reposition element center with screen center*/

    }


    .text-vertical-center {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;  */
        vertical-align: middle;
            margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .text-vertical-center h1 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 4.5em;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .text-vertical-center h3 {
        text-align: left;
    }



    /* Header */

    .header {
        display: table;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: yellow no-repeat center center scroll;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Smile test</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="css/ACo.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>

        <!-- Header -->
        <header id="top" class="header">
            <div class="text-vertical-center">

                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg" class="CenterScreen" style="display:inline" alt="Smilelogo" width="300" height="300">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-5">
                        <h3><a href="#">About</a></h3>
                        <h3><a href="#">Contact Us</a></h3>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: set img to `display:block`

Comment: Can you put the code together so we can see the result of the html and css?

Comment: @sniels Sure no problems. Added.

Comment: Please let me know this will help you or not https://jsfiddle.net/rqq8x5tx/1/

Answer (score 1):

For the smile use and modify the margin-top value for its start position

```
.CenterScreen{
   position:relative;
   width:50%;
   height:50%;
   margin:0 auto;
   margin-top:20%; 
}
```

and for the text use

```
.text-vertical-center {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- For your image, Add a max-width property of 100%. This would make it responsive.
- And for the text.. make it a 12 column row each text.. and text-align property to center.

together these two properties should help you achieve the result

Comment: If someone downvotes the answer, kindly state the reason as well. Helps me improve and understand.